# Blueprint context changes not reflecting while creating new page using DXA 1.2 and xpm

Tags: experience-manager, dxa, 2013-sp1, dxa-1.2

When I create a new page using the existing page types present in DXA 1.2 the components still get created in 400 Example Site Publication instead of getting created in 100 Master publication. I have already updated the blueprint context settings please find below the screenshot of the same.
[image]

Am I missing some step here ?

Comment: have you done any modification/ localization with items used in the page type in question?

Comment: I am using "Article Page" page type and I have not done any modification/localization.The blue print is the standard blueprint which comes as part of the DXA setup.

Comment: there is only one component on this page type, right? also check your settings are saved to honored by XPM.

Answer (score 4):

Just checked the `\400 Example Site\Building Blocks\Content\_Cloneable Content` content, actually `Article Component` attached on the Page type is created itself in `400 Example Site`. so you will get your new page's component created in 400 only.

if you create this component in master, you will get desired results.

Comment: Hello Raj, I have tried doing the suggested changes. Still facing the same issue.I created new page type with the components coming from 100 Master publication.

Answer (score 3):

In DXA 1.2, the OOTB Page Types and Content Types are defined in the 400 Example Site.  XPM doesn't allow you to create the Pages/Components higher in the BluePrint than where the Page/Component Types are defined.

In DXA 1.3, the Page/Content Types are defined higher up in the BluePrint (in a new Site Type Publication), which makes them re-usable and also allows you to create the Pages/Components higher up in the BluePrint.